# Como animar widgets dependiendo del DraggableScrollableSheet.?

Tags: flutter, animación

Como animar widgets dependiendo del DraggableScrollableSheet.?

Escuchar el porcentaje de desplazamiento mientras subo el DraggableScrollableSheet, baja el AppBar.

Comment: Se ve buena, si con el DraggableScrollableSheet puedes controlar el porcentaje de avance entonces puedes usarlo para mover el panel de arriba con un AnimatedPositioned quizás. Si no lo requieres con urgencia puedo hacer un video acerca de ello para mi canal :  www.youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: sii, eso se me ocurrió pero no se como hacerlo exactamente. Gracias Diego Esperaré tu video

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Una vez que tienes el `DraggableScrollableSheet` lo que necesitas es escuchar el porcentaje de desplazamiento, eso lo puedes hacer con `NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>` , luego de eso simplemente obtener el valor entre 0.0 y 1.0 para que puedas animar la vista superior.

Necesitas un `Stack` y `Positioned`.

Te dejo el ejemplo que hice:

```dart
const _googleMapsImage = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/4064/1*qYUvh-EtES8dtgKiBRiLsA.png';

class DraggableScrollableSheetAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DraggableScrollableSheetAnimationState createState() => _DraggableScrollableSheetAnimationState();
}

class _DraggableScrollableSheetAnimationState extends State<DraggableScrollableSheetAnimation> {
  double _percent = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
              child: Image.network(
                _googleMapsImage,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 20,
              top: 20,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () => null,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
                onNotification: (notification) {
                  setState(() {
                    _percent = 2 * notification.extent - 0.8;
                  });

                  return true;
                },
                child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  maxChildSize: 0.9,
                  minChildSize: 0.4,
                  initialChildSize: 0.4,
                  builder: (_, controller) {
                    return Material(
                      elevation: 10,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                        top: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 40,
                                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                                  height: 2,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Text(
                              'It\'s good to see you',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 13),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Text(
                              'Where are you going?',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 25),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.search,
                                  color: Colors.purple[300],
                                ),
                                hintText: 'Search destination',
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
                                controller: controller,
                                itemCount: 20,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                    leading: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
                                    title: Text('Address :$index'),
                                    subtitle: Text('City $index'),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: -170 * (1 - _percent),
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: _percent,
                child: _SearchDestination(),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: -50 * (1 - _percent),
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: _percent,
                child: _PickPlaceInMap(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PickPlaceInMap extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 10,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.place_sharp, color: Colors.grey),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text('Pick in the map'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SearchDestination extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 10,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              BackButton(),
              Text(
                'Choose destination',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                    filled: true,
                    hintText: 'Avenue 24 NO 219',
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                    filled: true,
                    hintText: 'Where are we going?',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También estaré publicando el video del proceso en mi canal de youtube: [www.youtube.com/diegoveloper](http://www.youtube.com/diegoveloper)